# AngularJS inject a singleton per view service

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, singleton

I am trying to negotiate a conceptual issue in AngularJS.
I have a controller that is currently using multiple services. Among this services, a few are used as a singleton **per** view. This means that once I enter a certain view (actually state since I am using Ui-Router), these specific services, which have some dependencies among themselves, are singleton(s).
However, when exiting this view and going later going back should instantiate new instances of them (and again being singletons for this state).
There are a few possible solution I came out with, all of them are not great:

1. Manually force instantiating them every time entering this view.
2. Manually force deleting from cache every time exiting this view.
3. Using a controller rather then using service/factory/provider.
4. Creating my own "factory" type, which will be implementing the angular's injection without being a singleton.

I was wondering if angular can offer some sort of "type" (such as non-singleton factory), that can solve this issue.

Comment: how about a singleton service that implements a factory method?

Comment: Thanks. Thats what I meant with creating my own factory type... I am looking for a more "built in" method.